# Swift 3 - how to disable adding row below last row?

Tags: swift

Edited as of Feb. 9 2017

I have a row called `Add Sections...` it suppose to add sections right above itself, I've made it not deletable, and unmovable but the problem is:

- If I decided to reorder one of the rows below the "Add Section..."
  row, you will be enabled to get it deleted and moved.

Any thoughts at all?

Comment: You should post working/compilable code, otherwise no-one can see if it's just a "shortcut" by you or a misuse of the framework.

Comment: I understand what do you mean, but I'm not going to post 400 code for trivial problem, my intent is to unable users to move any row below the "Add Section" row, is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you don't post the code that shows what you tried, then the answer is quite simple: Simply do the same as you did to "lock" the "Add Section..." row (e.g. implement the corresponding delegate methods to prevent locking)